# Fuzzy logic rule generator

Tags: logic, rule-engine, fuzzy-logic

I have 6 variables with 4 membership functions such as "tiny,small,large,huge".

Is there any tool available that would generate the rules for me. I tried to write the rules and came up with 200 rules but the combinations are killing me and it is still incomplete.

Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, it would help to add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Combining all input fuzzy sets in a naive way results in 4^6 = 4096 rules which is neither reasonable nor tractable (at least if you have to specify the rules' consequents manually). I'd rather recommend you to infer the rule base from data. The [machine learning framework for Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/mlf/) is a software package that can do this pretty nicely. It is commercial, but there is a free trial version. Have a try!

Cheers, UBod